# Remove search form from search result page in Drupal 8

Tags: theming, 8, search

What's the best way to remove the search form from the search result page in Drupal 8?

Comment: Is the form a block? You can disable the path visibility for search result paths.

Comment: No, it is not a block. There is a search form that is a block and I have that placed in a region. By default the search results page has a second search form that is not a block and there is no way to hide it from the admin. I don't want to have this second search form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much you can customize in core search. So you probably need to override [Drupal\search\Controller\SearchController::view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21src%21Controller%21SearchController.php/function/SearchController%3A%3Aview/8.4.x) and remove this line:

```
  $build['search_form'] = $this->formBuilder()->getForm(SearchPageForm::class, $entity);
```

Put your extended class into the route `search.view_node_search` in a [RouteSubscriber](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones).

But I don't think it's worth the effort. You can either simply hide the form in CSS or if you want a fully customizable search solution use [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question for Drupal 9 and first I hid it with css, then I found it can be disabled in /admin/config/search/pages/manage/node_search

Uncheck:
Display basic search
Display advanced search

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if is the best way, but you can remove it from your theme preprocess, just for that page:

`/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_search_api_page()
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_search_api_page(&$vars) {
  unset($vars['form']);
}`

Comment: This does not appear to work. Using hook_preprocess_HOOK() would be something like YOURTHEME_preprocess_page__search_api(&$vars) {}. That assumes the hook suggestion would be search_api, which I'm not certain it is. Furthermore, I think $vars['form'] would not be the correct array key to unset b/c the form would likely be found within a nested array starting with the page region name as the first key.